# Create a function that no matter how many times invoked run only when first async call finishes?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

suppose I've a function `fetch(id)`.

I would be calling it arbitrarily at random times.

But I want every successive call to run only after previous call has finished.

say the async task takes 4 seconds, and i call `fetch` 3 times. then total time should be 12 seconds.

I could make a array and at every call set promise to go through next in line.

but what are some ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, a promise queue would be a fine approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it

```
//First my example function which could be anything but should return promise which would be queued

function example(n) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            console.log(n);
            res();
        }, 1000);
    });
}


//now solution

function debounce(func) {

    let p = Promise.resolve();

    return function(x){
        p = p.then(() => func(x));
    }
}


//usage

d = debounce(example);
d(1);d(2);d(3);d(4);d(5);d(6);d(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain Promises without an array, just store a pointer to the last Promise

```
// async payload function
// returns a promise
function f(x) {
  console.log(`call f(${x})`);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`resolve f(${x})`);
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// wrapper to call function `f` sequentially
// stores pointer to the last Promise in closure
const g = (function(){
  let lastPromise = Promise.resolve();
  return function(arg){
    lastPromise = lastPromise.then(() => f(arg));
  }
})();

// generate random calls of function function `g`
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => g(i), Math.random() * 100);
}
```

Comment: wow i came to same solution, you could use Promise.resolve() which will run right away so wont need conditional

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [async.io](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library. 
Or, each time you want to call your function, push the function itself in an array. When the previous function has finished, check if there is still some functions to call in the array.

Comment: *How* would one use async.js? There's a bunch of functionality in there that's absolutely not useful here.